# Why is my file from image "request" incomplete when saving to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload an image from a URL to my Google Cloud Storage (Firebase). The following function shall return the file and a consecutive function will retrieve the actual Signed/Download Url to the new file. After all this I am updating a document in my Firestore Database with the new URL. That part works; the functions wait on uploading the (unfortunately incomplete) image and my document gets updated with the newly created file url. But the actual file/image is incomplete. :-(

```
async function saveToStorage(fileUrl) {
  var storage = admin.storage();
  var urlLib = require("url");
  var pathLib = require("path");
  //Get File Name from provided URL
  var parsed = urlLib.parse(fileUrl);
  var fileName = pathLib.basename(parsed.pathname);

  //Create Storage Reference with new File Name
  var bucket = storage.bucket('gs://myprojectname.appspot.com');
  //Path Folder
  var folderPath = 'data/photos/';
  //Path Folder + File
  var internalFilePath = folderPath + fileName ;
  //Bucket File Ref
  var file = bucket.file(internalFilePath);

  const request = require('request');

  const writeStream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: 'image/jpg'
    }
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.get(fileUrl)
        .pipe(writeStream)
        .on("error", (err) => {
            console.error(`Error occurred`);
            reject();
        })
        .on('finish', () => {
            console.info(`Photo saved`);
            resolve(file); 
        });
  });
}
```

The Image that is saved/uploaded/streamed to my Cloud Storage file looks like this:
[image: Incomplete Picture]

I have tried using node-fetch and request and rewrote my function in several ways, but always turn out with this result. I'm sure it has something to do with how I use my Promise, because if I omit the Promise the file actually completes but then the main code keeps executing instead of waiting for this Promise.

This has the same result (incomplete file):

```
return await fetch(fileUrl).then(res => { 

    const contentType = res.headers.get('content-type');
    const writeStream = file.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
        contentType
        }
    });

    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        res.body.pipe(writeStream);
        writeStream.on('finish', function() {
            console.log("Stream finished")
            resolve(file);
        });
        writeStream.on('error', function() {
            reject(new Error("Whoops!"));
        });
    });

    return p.then(
        function(file) {
            console.log('Photo saved');
            return file},
        function(error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        });
    });
```

And outright returning the stream writes a complete file, but my main code is not waiting for the file (and I need to handle the file)..

```
    return res.body.pipe(writeStream)
      .on('finish', () => {        
        return file;
        console.log('Photo')
      })
      .on('error', err => {
        return console.error(err);
      });
```

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 2):

So this is the code that finally worked for me.

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

     const req = request(fileUrl);
     req.pause();
     req.on('response', res => {

        const writeStream = file.createWriteStream({
          metadata: {
            contentType: res.headers['content-type']
          }
        });

        req.pipe(writeStream)
          .on('finish', () => {
            console.log('Photo saved');
            resolve(file);
          })
          .on('error', err => {
            writeStream.end();
            console.error(err);
            reject();
          });

        req.resume();  

     });
     req.on('error', err => console.error(err));   
  });
```